# How to run shells like SQLite from PowerShell ISE?

Tags: sqlite, powershell, powershell-ise

I want to do some things with sqlite3.exe, the sqlite3 command line shell. After navigating to the directory in PowerShell ISE, I run the program with `.\sqlite3.exe` and get the expected output from SQLite:

```
___________________________________________________________
PS [path]\SQLite shell> .\sqlite3.exe
SQLite version 3.7.14 2012-09-03 15:42:36
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
```

However, if I try typing `.help` after this, or any other command for that matter, nothing happens and the bottom taskbar says "Already running a command. Please wait.". Of course, there is nothing to wait for, because clearly sqlite3.exe is waiting for input from *me*.

I cannot get PowerShell ISE to respond to any further commands after this point unless I quit SQLite with Ctrl+Break.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Powershell ISE isn't like the normal Powershell console. Powershell ISE is a host built on WPF which you'll find certain legacy exe commands do not work correctly in ISE. These are normally interactive exe commands and not just sqlite3.exe. For example I've had issues with logparser.exe in ISE also.

Try running it in poweshell.exe

Comment: I was already able to run it in powershell.exe (or cmd.exe for that matter) but the main benefit of ISE to me is consistent copy/paste functionality and hotkeys, and better output console behavior. So I'll take your answer to mean that what I want to do (namely use sqlite3.exe in something that isn't the cmd-style windows terminal) is impossible?

Comment: That's correct some console applications and in particular interactive console applications like sqllite3.exe will not work in Powershell ISE, but work fine in Powershell.exe